# Why the reverse DNS lookup of SPN during initial phase of Kerberos authentication?

Tags: kerberos, mitkerberos

At its base, Kerberos isn't an overly complicated protocol. I have also already successfully configured a server to accept Kerberos authentications via SPNEGO HTTP headers. I'm new in this area though, so maybe I have just overlooked something...

**The confusing part** of Kerberos and their implementations is the *optional* reverse DNS lookup of server's hostname made by clients before they send the resulting SPN to KDC in order to obtain a ticket for the server / application identified by that SPN. As a result, clients may either use the originally requested hostname (*this may be an alias - CNAME*), OR the reverse-looked up name of the IP-address-owning server in the resulting SPN. This complicates Kerberos setups greatly.

The Kerberos specification ([RFC 4120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4120)) seems to prefer avoiding the reverse lookup (also referred to as "canonicalization"):

> 1.3.  Choosing a Principal with Which to Communicate
>
> ...
>
> Implementation note: Many current implementations do some degree of
> canonicalization of the provided service name, often using DNS even
> though it creates security problems.  However, there is no
> consistency among implementations as to whether the service name is
> case folded to lowercase or whether reverse resolution is used.  To
> maximize interoperability and security, applications SHOULD provide
> security mechanisms with names that result from folding the user-
> entered name to lowercase without performing any other modifications
> or canonicalization.

For example, the widespread MIT Kerberos implementation gives an option to disable the reverse lookup and there are even several scenarios suggesting when the reverse lookup should be disabled, in [their documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/princ_dns.html). On the other side, in Windows the reverse lookup seems to be pretty much hard-coded (see a related question [Globally disable reverse DNS lookup for Kerberos on Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/995631/globally-disable-reverse-dns-lookup-for-kerberos-on-windows)).

**The problem** is that the reverse lookups not only break the usage of server aliases (CNAMES), but their optional-ity can cause really unexpected and unstable behavior when different programs on the same machine decide to handle it differently. Like for example when [Fiddler makes Kerberos authentication work](https://www.telerik.com/forums/fiddler-makes-kerberos-auth-work). And from my tests, the current Firefox, unlike Chrome or IE, even rejects to send Keberos token to a server if requested hostname and hostname looked up by a used Kerberos client library don't match.

So here comes the question: **Why** is there this mostly problematic default behavior of Kerberos clients? **Is there any *real* benefit nowadays** from doing the reverse lookups, other than to maybe get FQDN of a server when FQDN isn't supplied, or to be "backwards-compatible"? Isn't the identity of the called server somewhat confirmed by the widespread usage of SSL anyway?

A bonus question: No new standard coping with this Kerberos "quirk" on the way?

Comment: There’s a good article somewhere (not MS) about using canonicalisation to ensure single host address / SPN, to avoid the burden of having to support the all calling parties’ arbitrary aliases.  That concept is the closest thing I’ve seen to a purpose for the canonicalisation, but it doesn’t address why it’s optional or even not preferred.

Comment: @Chalky, thanks for your feedback. It seems like no one, maybe from the authors (MS?) themselves, really understand the purpose. I wonder what it means "to avoid the burden of having to support the all calling parties’ arbitrary aliases" - I can't see any burden myself here. Maybe you could try to explain?

Comment: Note that from what I've seen, there is usually just one hostname (possibly CNAME alias) used for a target application running on a server that needs to be registered in Kerberos (AD). That's why I can't see the problem in here.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the burden of having to create/support multiple SPNs.  I agree, a service should ideally have a single address, but web farm etc proxies don’t always help us in this area, and I suspect it all fell into the too-hard basket and not canonicalising became the easier path.

Answer (score 3):

I've always assumed it's to break CNAMES.

Comment: I have just edited my question, so that it is more clear for newcomers. I can confirm that the reverse lookups "break CNAMES". But the question is about why they even exist...

Comment: To be honest, from my experience with MIT Kerberos (non-AD), it always seemed to _help_ with using CNAMEs more than break them. It meant the host only ever needed a single SPN for a particular service even if it was known under multiple names.

Comment: If the host is serving multiple services then it totally breaks things.
Given that most web servers are virtual hosts/proxys/loadblancers it really makes life hard.  It would be much easier to register a few different CNAMEs than give every different service principal it's own A record, and possibly even a different host IP and reverse Ptr record.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is probably the reason why my keberoized application works well out of Windows box (with only a SPN of the CNAME), however need another SPN of the hostname for the application to run out of Unix.